# Sort according to two columns and extract top two based on last column

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, extract, uniq

I have a file with three columns. I would like to extract rows with top two values in column 3 for each unique value in column 2.

```
cat file.list
run1/xx2/x2c1.txt 21 -190
run1/xx2/x2c2.txt 19 -180
run1/xx2/x2c3.txt 18 -179
run1/xx2/x2c4.txt 19 -162
run1/xx2/x2c5.txt 21 -172
run2/xx2/x2c1.txt 21 -162
run2/xx2/x2c2.txt 18 -192
run2/xx2/x2c3.txt 19 -191
run2/xx2/x2c4.txt 19 -184
run2/xx2/x2c5.txt 21 -179
run3/xx2/x2c1.txt 19 -162
run3/xx2/x2c2.txt 19 -192
run3/xx2/x2c3.txt 21 -191
run3/xx2/x2c4.txt 18 -184
run3/xx2/x2c5.txt 19 -179
```

expected output

```
run2/xx2/x2c2.txt 18 -192
run3/xx2/x2c4.txt 18 -184
run3/xx2/x2c2.txt 19 -192
run2/xx2/x2c3.txt 19 -191
run3/xx2/x2c3.txt 21 -191
run1/xx2/x2c1.txt 21 -190
```

I feel like some combination of sort, uniq and awk might accomplish but I can't properly execute it. I can sort by columns

```
sort -nk2 -nk3 file.list
```

which gives me an output sorted by -k2 and -k3 as follows,

```
run2/xx2/x2c2.txt 18 -192
run3/xx2/x2c4.txt 18 -184
run1/xx2/x2c3.txt 18 -179
run3/xx2/x2c2.txt 19 -192
run2/xx2/x2c3.txt 19 -191
run2/xx2/x2c4.txt 19 -184
run1/xx2/x2c2.txt 19 -180
run3/xx2/x2c5.txt 19 -179
run1/xx2/x2c4.txt 19 -162
run3/xx2/x2c1.txt 19 -162
run3/xx2/x2c3.txt 21 -191
run1/xx2/x2c1.txt 21 -190
run2/xx2/x2c5.txt 21 -179
run1/xx2/x2c5.txt 21 -172
run2/xx2/x2c1.txt 21 -162
```

but then I get stuck on how to extract only the rows with best two scores in the last column for 18, 19 and 20.

I  would really appreciate any bash solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Piping the current `sort` results to `awk`:

```
$ sort -nk2 -nk3 file.list | awk 'a[$2]++ < 2'
run2/xx2/x2c2.txt 18 -192
run3/xx2/x2c4.txt 18 -184
run3/xx2/x2c2.txt 19 -192
run2/xx2/x2c3.txt 19 -191
run3/xx2/x2c3.txt 21 -191
run1/xx2/x2c1.txt 21 -190
```

Where:

- field #2 (`$2`) is used as the index for array `a[]`
- if the value stored in the array is less than 2 then print the current input line
- then increment the counter (`++`)
- 1st time we see `a[18]` the count is 0, we print the line, and increment the count by 1
- 2nd time we see `a[18]` the count is 1, we print the line, and increment the count by 1
- 3rd (to nth) time we see `a[18]` the count is greater than or equal to 2, we do *not* print the line, and increment the count

An alternative where we increment the count first:

```
$ sort -nk2 -nk3 file.list | awk '++a[$2] <= 2'
run2/xx2/x2c2.txt 18 -192
run3/xx2/x2c4.txt 18 -184
run3/xx2/x2c2.txt 19 -192
run2/xx2/x2c3.txt 19 -191
run3/xx2/x2c3.txt 21 -191
run1/xx2/x2c1.txt 21 -190
```